# [ubuntu 16.04][dual-boot] ubuntu lagging on a good spec laptop

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, crash

I have an 8gb i5 7th gen HP laptop with 1Tb harddisk on it.I made this dualboot 6 months ago to run some hard core IDE's .At that time, I didn't had much knowledge about swaps and partitions(umm, i still don't) so I allocated about 34.1 gb free and installed ubuntu there.
Now the current situtation is i have 4 harddisk partitions(windows, local disk e,f, programming) which are shown in both ubuntu and windows. **But my laptop has recently started hanging like hell!!!**
I am guessing that it might be due to some memory issues,because as far as i remember, i have installed a bunch of cutomisation tools like unity tweak tool, compiz sonfig, emulators, many text editors, some ubuntu themes, some graphical softwares and some big  applications like eclipse, Android Studio, Codeblocks,Opera,mozilla,etc .And it was showing an alert recently saying only 1gb of space left...

My question is : **how can i make it work smoothly?** if it is about partitions, i have read read some very dreadful cases of harddisk failure due to dual booting. *I  can login from windows and allocate upto 50 gb more of free space from there.*
Plus, how can i get a list of all application installed on my laptop, and there locations where they are installed(and ultimately, unistall them easily? all i know is `sudo apt-get remove <packagename>`)?

Answer (score 0):

To see installed programs run:

```
dpkg -l
```

Usualy programs are in */usr/bin/* but you can search for then using a command like

```
find / -name program_name
```